# Load test Oracle Apex applications

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c, oracle-apex21.2

I have various Oracle apex apps which are session encrypted, protected and on friendly URLs. My objective is to load test the apps. My team is using NeoLoad but it is causing so many issues because of session encryption and protection as HTTP request gets changed.

Is there any tool which is optimized for Load testing apex apps?

Comment: Any load testing app just submits requests to the server. How would you "optimize" that for APEX vs any other web app in a way that wouldn't negate the value of the test as a normal web client? The object is to optimize the app to meet the load. Can you tell where the bottleneck in your app is? Not that it isn't a good guess regardless, but what makes you suspect the encryption? Is there anything you can do to improve the performance of the server around that function?